# Stolen iPhone disappeared from "Find My iPhone"

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

My iPhone 11 got stolen yesterday. The "Find My iPhone" feature was enabled on it so I tried using iCloud to find it. I was able to see it on "iCloud Find My iPhone" until today and suddenly it got disappeared from the list and I wasn't able to see it anymore. When I go to account setting I still can see it under My devices but it doesn't show up in the Find iPhone section.
Does anyone know what has happened and is there anything that I can do to get it back on the list?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The phone was probably turned off

Comment: Did you lock the device while it was visible? Did you file a police report?

Comment: yes, I clicked on the lost mode. The weird thing is that at some point, I was able to see it moving on the map. but suddenly it didn't show up anymore and got removed from my devices list.